# Ubuntu 20.04 32 bit

Tags: 20.04, kernel

What I am asking today is if it is possible to generate a 32 bit version of Ubuntu 20.04. Is there a group or community working on a such project?

Comment: Wrong place to ask since we only support official Ubuntu.  Mind that debian still supports 32-bit. Plus you could form a group on ubuntuforums :)

Comment: Ubuntu built all i386 packages up to the completion of the *disco* cycle (ie. 19.04, with Lubuntu & Xubuntu having dailies in the *alpha* stage so any installs had packages the entire life of 19.04), with the builds being turned off just prior to *eoan* being released.  Packages are still built for *bionic* (18.04) though.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi version of Ubuntu 20.04 is, I believe, for 32-bit Raspbian systems..

Comment: You are better off spending 200 euro and get a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @Rinzwind I agree with that whole heartedly. You can also get an old used one for cheaper, if you would like.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I am not sure it is the wrong place to ask. 
There might be a solution within the scope of askubuntu or not. 
Whoever asks doesn't know that in the first place (that's why he is asking).
The answer could well be "No, there isn't...", but that doesn't make the question "improper" for the site.

Comment: Nope. @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Canonical ditched 32-bit and the ISO has been cleared from 32-bit parts except for a couple of libraries. So there is no way to use UBUNTU for this. You'd need debian to recreate an spin off.

Comment: @Rinzwind - That is fine... what I mean is that it may be a good answer (for the negative) to a *valid question*.
Otherwise, one would be asking the asker to know the answer to his own question, prior to asking, so he doesn't ask...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_time_loops

Answer (score 4):

There is, as of today, no known group working on a 32-bit version of Ubuntu Desktop. (Ubuntu Server is different)

Any group of volunteers that wishes to organize itself and do so is welcome. You don't need anybody's permission.

Ubuntu dropped 32-bit Ubuntu Desktop simply because there were too few community members doing the work to keep that version viable. The technical debt of bugs and poor performance on 32-bit hardware became onerous. Ubuntu has added and removed flavors and architectures before based upon the waxing and waning of community involvement.

Any group interested in pursuing this project is likely to find that coordinating with the previous developers at http://discourse.ubuntu.com will save a lot of pain re-discovering the issues and re-inventing products and processes that already exist to support other projects.

Alternately, Debian maintains 32-bit desktop environments with a variety of desktop environments to choose from. And they work well.

Comment: Can I edit your answer to add the information that users can use Debian 32 bit instead of rebuilding and maintaining Ubuntu 32 bit, and that the user experience in Debian would be very similar to Ubuntu ?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi added a final paragraph. Feel free to edit to taste.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that it is possible to run 32-bit Ubuntu 20.04.

However, this guide may provide some information.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/no-ubuntu-32-bit-iso-what-now/

Debian Linux, on the other hand, always has a 32-bit image. You can download it from this Debian page: https://www.debian.org/distrib/

Make sure to look for "32-bit PC netinst ISO"

I would recommend installing Debian 10, as it is the newest version.

Comment: Where does the OP say that he want a Raspberry Pi version ?

Comment: All I am saying is that it is Raspberry Pi compatible. If he wants a 32-bit version, he can create the image and install it on any computer regardless of the fact that he may or may not be using a Raspberry Pi. For instance, he can install the 32-bit image on any 32-bit system, but he cannot install 64-bit image on a 32-bit system.

Comment: The Raspberry PI uses ARM CPU / architecture, normal PC's uses INTEL / AMD ... they are not compatible !!!

Comment: Alright, thank you for clearing that up. I forgot that Raspbian is ARM.

Comment: I made some edits. Does that help?